# Trying to get date and time, but getting years and months sumed up

Tags: javascript, date, selenium-ide

Im using selenium ide and trying to get date and time in format like yyyymmddhhmi, but getting yyyy sumed up with mm (example: I need to get 201511041515, but I get 2026041515), please help, here is my code:

`var d= new Date(); 
var y=d.getFullYear(); 
var m=( (d.getMonth()+1)<10) ? '0'+(d.getMonth()+1) : (d.getMonth()+1); 
var c=( (d.getDate())<10) ? '0'+(d.getDate()) : (d.getDate()); 
var h=( (d.getHours())<10) ? '0'+(d.getHours()) : (d.getHours()); 
var n=( (d.getMinutes())<10) ? '0'+(d.getMinutes()) : (d.getMinutes()); y+m+c+h+n;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing integer summation. It's not doing string concatenation.
If you do this:

```
''+y+m+c+h+n
"201511041225"
```

It will work.